# Avoid query to check if relation exists in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

In Laravel I've 2 models `Man` and `Car`, and the `Car` model has a foreign key `man_id`.

Now I would like to check if a `Car` has an owner, so I can do
`if($car->man != null)`

I could also do:
`if($car->man_id != null)`
but I don't like this solution...

But in this way Laravel do a query to check if `Man` exists, is there a way to avoid this useless query?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new function on your `Car` model that checks for its owner.

*Car.php*

```
class Car extends Model {

   public function hasOwner()
   {
      return empty($this->man_id); // returns boolean
   }
}
```

Then, you can just do

```
$car = Car::first();
if ($car->hasOwner()) { ... }
```

*UPDATE:*

You can also use [exists()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists) method

```
$car->man()->exists(); // bool: true if there is at least one row
```

As of Laravel 5.5 or higher, you can also use [doesntExist()](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists) which will determine if no rows exist for the current query.

```
$car->man()->doesntExist(); // bool: true if no row exists
```

Comment: yes, this is a solution, but isn't there a "standard way" already implemented in Laravel to do this?